# immunotherapy - how would the inhibitor detect

Tags: cell-biology, immunology, cancer

It's a known fact that if PD-L1 happens to be on cancer cells, it will signall `off` to the T-cell's receptor(PD-1) to turn off its activation, resulting in a fact that cancer cell won't be destroyed.

**Question 1:** Even if with immunotherapy, we stop the blockage (PD-1 vs PD-L1), (Let's say PD-L1 was expressed high with NGS), why does this mean that T-cell now will kill the cancer cell ? Yes, we removed the blockage, but it could still happen that binding between the proteins of T-cell and proteins of cancer cells might still result in NO T-activation, hence no cancer cells being killed. So If I'm right, having PD-L1 expression high on NGS still doesn't give you anything and you gotta risk it and see !

**Question 2:** It turns out some healthy cells also have PD-L1 expression on them, but much less amount than on cancer cells. For simplicity and example, let's take our body's own cell (cell-Y - I just named it up). This cell-Y has PD-L1 as well. If we give the Atezolizumab(tecentrik) to the body, which will stop the blockage between PD-1 vs PD-L1, would the T-cell now destroy this cell-Y ? I'm asking this because it's said that using PD-L1 inhibitors also cause good cells to destroy. But I don't get why. Even after stopping the blockage, T-cell shouldn't kill cell-Y, because this cell-Y is body's own cell, the other proteins it has on the surface, binding it to the T-cell, still shouldn't cause destruction. What do you think ? or this is random and nobody knows ! the only protection our immune system had for cell-Y was PD-L1 on it, but if we block it, then we get to the random scenario and got no idea whether T-cell now can destroy it or not(depending on their receptors binding). Question is, do we actually get to the random scenario or we know for sure that without PD-L1 on cell-Y, T-cell will always kill it ?

**Question 3**: How is it possible that with tecentrik immunotherapy, T-cells don't kill good cells, but kill cancer cells ? I've read somewhere that it's about the dosage and frequency, but how would that work ? how does the process differ between giving high dose of tecentrik and low dose in a sense that it's possible that T-cell won't kill good cell even after blocking PD-1 vs PD-L1 ?

Comment: These are technically complex questions. Can you please restrict yourself to one question per question?

Comment: Can you link or cite sources for your statements? It would be nice to look at the basis for your question to evaluate how best to answer it. (Also, Chris is right)